# Getting Gallery Images Centered in Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

Trying to get the gallery pictures on the following page centered in my mobile phone: http://tinyurl.com/o5c69lc

The CSS code that I am using is the following, but that doesn't make a difference. Any thoughts?

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .gallery_holder ul li { margin-left:-10px; }
```

Comment: `@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .gallery_holder ul li { margin-left:-10px; }}`

Comment: If you have an element, and it is `inline` or `inline-block` (images default to inline block), and set the containing element of that element to have `text-align: center` the element will be centered. You don't want to necessarily use margin for centering

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel Thank you. I just set that to center, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let me get a better idea of your exact styling. The `li` contains the image you want to center right?

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel, yes.

Comment: Check your media query dimensions and that the device you're view the page on is actually between 320 and 480 px. otherwise, this media query isn't going to be called.

Comment: @Cruiser, yes, it is between 320 and 480 px.

Comment: can you post your code, perhaps in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Cruiser https://jsfiddle.net/jrzozcmz/

Comment: I think the best way to approach it is (and I'm making a few assumptions about your design), to make the `li`s fullwidth--or close to fullwidth--and then set the li to have `text-align: center`, so that if the image is a direct child of it, it should be centered. Unless the image is overridden to be `display: block`.